# Cannot make array unique in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to make ClothingCollection in ruby, one of the tasks of which is to return an array of types of clothes.
I have 17 files (name of clothing, type and for what weather it is made) and 5 types.

```
require_relative 'clothing'

class ClothingCollection
  @@types_of_clothes = []

  def initialize(clothing)
    @type = clothing.type_of_clothing
  end

  def set_type_to_catalog
    unless @@types_of_clothes.include?(@type)
      @@types_of_clothes << @type
    end
  end
end
```

Please, what's wrong with this code?
It returns 10 types

```
hat
jeans
top
outerwear
shoes
hat
jeans
top
outerwear
shoes
```

I have also tried the `.uniq` method and it also does not work

Comment: Are you sure those are unique values? What does `@@types_of_clothes.inspect` reveal? `uniq` will only work if the values them selves respond to `eql?` properly which a custom class may not.

Comment: It's worth noting that using class variables like this an anti-pattern and it's better to intermediate between class and instance of classes with class methods, like in this case `self.types` could wrap around an internal array or `Set`.

Comment: try `@@types_of_clothes << @type.strip`